# Xamarin / C# : How to iterate through Array/List DataMember passed to the viewCell without using inner ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, data-binding, runtime

I've been advised that Xamarin doesn't support **nested ListViews**.. I trying to build social app, in which the **post** might have **several images and comments**.

The feed page will be basically a **ListView** of the posts. While I cannot use a listView within the post (which is a viewCell), I tried to use **Grid** for the **images** instead, and another **Grid** for **Comments**. Both Images and Comments can be Lists, Arrays or ObservableCollections in the "post" Class.

Now I need to make foreach loop of this array/list, adding images with source bound to array item. But it seems to me, I couldn't use the data passed to the viewCell in C# (can only be used in Xaml layout).

Anybody has any ideas how to solve this.

```
[DataContract]
Public class post {
   [DataMember]
   List<comment> commentContainer {get; set;}
   [DataMember]
   List<String> imageContainer {get; set;}
}
```

in Xaml of cellView

```
<Grid x:Name="imagesGrid" IsVisible="{Binding isImage}" BindingContext="{Binding imageContainer}">
        here I need to iterate the list of image in c# if possible - runtime- !
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right to say that you shouldn't use nested `ListViews` in *Xamarin.Forms*, virtualization goes out the window and scrolling/gestures will be hard to handle.

However, i think this design in *Xamarin.Forms* will be fraught with problems. *Xamarin.Forms* `ListView` is a very specific beast and wont play well with very complicated layouts. My gut feeling is you want to do this in [Native Views](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/native-views/) maybe or at the very least design this entirely in code. Anyway that is just my gut feel.

Have it be noted, i would shy away from this design and make it simple for your self by doing like *WhatsApp* does, and use a *Template Selector* and break apart multiple images and posts with a [`DataTemplateSelecto`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/). Then you Don't have to worry about complicated layouts.

However, if you have your heart set on more complicated layouts inside `ListView` (be warned there be dragons) though you can take a look at this, [Cell Appearance](http://Cell%20Appearance) As noted i would be more inclined to this entirely in *Code* apposed to an ad-hock *Xaml* solution

```
public class CustomCell : ViewCell
{
    public CustomCell()
    {
        //instantiate each of our views
        var image = new Image ();
        StackLayout cellWrapper = new StackLayout ();
        StackLayout horizontalLayout = new StackLayout ();
        Label left = new Label ();
        Label right = new Label ();

        ...

        //add views to the view hierarchy
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add (image);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add (left);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add (right);
        cellWrapper.Children.Add (horizontalLayout);
        View = cellWrapper;
    }
}
```

And set it like this

```
public partial class ImageCellPage : ContentPage
{
    public ImageCellPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(CustomCell));
    }
}
```

Also checkout [`Grid`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/)

You can build one in code like this

```
var grid = new Grid();

grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});

var topLeft = new Label { Text = "Top Left" };
var topRight = new Label { Text = "Top Right" };
var bottomLeft = new Label { Text = "Bottom Left" };
var bottomRight = new Label { Text = "Bottom Right" };

grid.Children.Add(topLeft, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(topRight, 0, 1);
grid.Children.Add(bottomLeft, 1, 0);
grid.Children.Add(bottomRight, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Got your point.. but this customCell will again show one image per cell.. This is not the intended feel.. Imagine you're using facebook and posting several images in one post.. for sure, you wouldn't like the app to treat each as separate post! The same applies for comments (I may hide them as twitter does).

Comment: @MohammedA.Najjar i understand you, and i do wish you the lbest luck, this is just a post based on my experience. remember facebook and twiter have unlimited resources to make thier apps perfect in a native environment, Xamarin.Forms Listview will just be hard to tame with complicated dynamic layouts. However DataTemplateSelector might get you out of trouble, you can up to 20 layouts on android i believ

Comment: Clear enough.. Much appreciated Michael.. Thank you so much. This would help me in another feature as well.. Really helpful